# unnamed json array into java

Tags: java, json, gson

I have the following string:

```
"[{\"type\":\"string\",\"value\":\"value1\",\"field\":\"label\"},
    {\"type\":\"string\",\"value\":\"value2\",\"field\":\"address_unique\"}]"
```

and I want to turn this into java GSON JsonObject array/list in order to invoke something like:

```
myJsonObjs[i].getAsJsonPrimitive("value").getAsString();
```

What is the shortest path to achieve this? I tried setting up a bean like this:

```
public static class Filter {
    @SerializedName("type")
    private String type;
    @SerializedName("value")
    private String value;
    @SerializedName("field")
    private String field;

    //getters, setters and ctor
}
```

but I cannot find a way to deserialize the string above into an array/list of this bean using JsonParser or Gson. In particular I tried

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
gson.fromJson(json_string, Filter[].class);
```

(where `json_string` is the string above) but this gives me a

```
IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Have you tried a list: `gson.fromJson(json_string, new TypeToken<List<Filter>>(){}.getType())`?

Comment: That gives the same ex: `IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING`...

Comment: Ok, I'm a silly guy: it was an escaping problem... Doing `json_string.replace("\\","").replace("\"[", "[").replace("]\"","]");` solved the problem... Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one way of doing it:

```
final String json = "[{\"type\":\"string\",\"value\":\"value1\",\"field\":\"label\"},{\"type\":\"string\",\"value\":\"value2\",\"field\":\"address_unique\"}]";
final JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
final JsonElement rootElement = parser.parse(json);
final JsonArray values = rootElement.getAsJsonArray();
for (final JsonElement value : values) {
    final JsonObject obj = value.getAsJsonObject();
    final Filter filter = new Filter();
    filter.setType(obj.get("type"));
    filter.setValue(obj.get("value"));
    filter.setField(obj.get("field"));
}
```

And here is a more automated way:

```
final String json = "[{\"type\":\"string\",\"value\":\"value1\",\"field\":\"label\"},{\"type\":\"string\",\"value\":\"value2\",\"field\":\"address_unique\"}]";
final TypeToken<List<Filter>> token = new TypeToken<List<Filter>>() {
};
final Gson gson = new Gson();
final List<Filter> values = gson.fromJson(json, token.getType());
```

Comment: Well, while reading your answer I realized I have a couple of " I should get rid of. In particular `json_string.replace("\\","").replace("\"[", "[").replace("]\"","]");`. With that your answer works great! Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

What have you tried with parse? What you have there is a string, you need two steps

1. parse the string into a JsonArray
2. Convert the JsonArray to the java object with fromJson

Answer (score 0):

This looks strange, your code should work...
Anyway you could also try [Genson library](http://code.google.com/p/genson/), it has similar features to Gson plus some others and better performances.

Here is how to achieve it with Genson:

```
Genson genson = new Genson();
Filter[] filters = genson.deserialize(json, Filter[].class);

// or if you need a list
List<Filter> filters = genson.deserialize(json, new GenericType<List<Filter>>(){});
```

Answer (score 0):

it can be first parsed into an array, then converted to a list.

```
final Gson gson = new Gson();
final Filter[] values = gson.fromJson(json, Filter[].class);
ArrayList< Filter > filterList = new ArrayList< Filter >(Arrays.asList(values));
```