# JSON unnamed arrays to Java Object

Tags: java, json, gson

I'm trying to convert the following JSON-object

```
{"myFirstArray":[[266.38,0.196],[266.37,3.399],[266.35,0.192],[266.33,0.101],[266.32,0.214],[266.29,0.203],[266.24,6.54],[266,1],[265.94,4.617],[265.73,2.13],[265.72,6.576],[265.71,0.049],[265.68,17.87],[265.67,39.191],[265.51,0.01],[265.18,0.793],[265.11,0.04],[265.01,0.544],[265,22.919],[264.82,3.493]],"mySecondArray":[[268.54,0.354],[268.29,0.3],[268.26,1.336],[268.15,0.01],[267.97,7.247],[267.96,10],[267.88,0.052],[267.77,0.013],[267.74,40.992],[267.71,20],[267.7,0.506],[267.65,0.075],[267.53,5.568],[267.49,0.064],[267.48,0.096],[267.34,0.71],[267.23,2.675],[267.19,32],[267,1.05],[266.9,0.98]],"simpleObject":"1234"}
```

to the Java class `MyObject` (below), I'm currently using GSON, but can not find any documentation or examples on how to convert arrays of unnamed values.

```
public class MyObject{
    Pair myFirstArray[];
    Pair myFirstArray[];
    int simpleObject;
}
public class Pair {
    float foo;
    float bar;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14205743/unnamed-json-array-into-java

Comment: have you tried [jsonschema2pojo.org](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) ? Copy your JSON int the textarea and select JSON as source. Select the necessary settings you would like to receive, for example GSON und click on preview. Test the retrieved classes with it. For the unnamed arrays, it will create something like this: `private List<List<Double>> myFirstArray = new ArrayList<List<Double>>();`